# Using SumoLogic for angular2+ Logs

Tags: angular, user-interface, logging, sumologic

Is there a way for me to use : Use sumologic (https://www.sumologic.com/) in my angular2+ application ? Have googled but have not found anything that suggests I can use it?

Comment: Whatz the reason for downvoting may I know ?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried yet !

But yes you can just follow these steps -

1. run `npm i sumologic --save`
2. As per documentation add this code into your `constructor` or `ngOnInit` hook of component
         var SumoLogger = require('sumologic')

   ```
     // Optional opts
     var opts = {
     request // wrapper around https://www.npmjs.com/package/request (useful for testing)
     endpoint // default https://collectors.au.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/, change again mostly to aid testing/debugging
     syncInterval // how often we should sync to sumo logic (default ever second)
     };

     var logger = new SumoLogger('SUMOLOGIC-HTTP-COLLECTOR-CODE' /*, opts */);

     // optional - if you would like console.log to go to sumo logic
     logger.replaceConsole()

     // optional - if you would like console.log to go to sumo logic and stdout
     logger.augmentConsole()

     logger.log("Yeah, it worked");
   ```

It should work. any problem let me know.

Comment: @pradeep-jain : I am just starting up on angular..hence can you clarify which part of documentation you are referring and how to as you say 'hook'. It seems this is all nodejs code.

Comment: I am referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/sumologic this documentation, for `hook` refer here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks